# Why can a nested function using a regular variable can't change the namesake variable in the outer scope, while one using an item in a list can?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the reason that the nested function in the first example using a regular variable can't change the variable in the outer scope, while the one in the second example using an item in a list can?

I am looking for an answer from language design perspective.

Thanks.

Example one:

```
def make_counter():
    count = 0
    def counter():
        count += 1
        return count
    return counter
```

Example two:

```
def make_counter():
    count = [0]
    def counter():
        count[0] += 1
        return count[0]
    return counter
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because integers in python are imutable, while lists are not.

Hence, when you write `count += 1`, this is equivalent to

```
count = count + 1
```

which creates a new variable (which is then local to `counter`), in contrast, when you write `count[0] += 1` this is equivalent to

```
value = count[0]
value = value + 1
count[0] = value
```

here, `count` has not been re-assigned to any new value, and you modify the original `count`, created outside the inner function, by assigning the (newly created) `value` to it.

Answer (score 2):

Python closures work exactly like this.

All free variables (i.e. variables which are neither local vars, nor arguments) are saved in the internal `__closure__` property.

```
In [1394]: def make_counter():
      ...:     count = 0
      ...:     def counter():
      ...:         nonlocal count
      ...:         count += 1
      ...:         return count
      ...:     return counter
      ...: 
In [1395]: f = make_counter()

In [1396]: f
Out[1396]: <function __main__.make_counter.<locals>.counter>

In [1397]: f.__closure__
Out[1397]: (<cell at 0x10af4bd98: int object at 0x10024ac20>,)

In [1399]: f.__closure__[0].cell_contents
Out[1399]: 0
```

It just so happens that, in the first case, `int`s are immutable, so you are not modifying the original `count`.

When `f` is called, the inner function has its own environment frame is created which contains local variable `count` and is merged with `__closure__`.

Try calling `f`, and the counter is incremented:

```
In [1400]: f()
Out[1400]: 1

In [1401]: f.__closure__[0].cell_contents
Out[1401]: 1
```

In the latter case, you're modifying an entry in the list, which is mutable. The reference is copied into the `__closure__` property.

By the way, `make_counter` is a global function, and so has an empty `__closure__` attribute:

```
In [1403]: print(make_counter.__closure__)
None
```

---

Your second example, modified a bit:

```
In [1404]: def make_counter():
      ...:     count = [0]
      ...:     print(id(count))
      ...:     def counter():
      ...:         nonlocal count
      ...:         count[0] += 1
      ...:         return count[0]
      ...:     return counter
      ...: 

In [1405]: f = make_counter()
4495587464

In [1408]: id(f.__closure__[0].cell_contents)
Out[1408]: 4495587464
```

The `id` is identical.